# construct a path connected space which behaves badly for locally path connectedness

Tags: general-topology

Find a subspace of $R^{2}$ that is path connected but not locally path connected at each of its points.

I know that comb space is path connected but not locally path connected.The problem is that comb space is locally connected at some of its points.I don't know how to construct the desired space with weird property.

Comment: Did you mean not locally path connected at "any" of its points? In other words, the space is path connected but at no point of the space is it locally connected.

Comment: Yes,that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hatcher](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATchapters.html), chapter $0$, page 18 has an example. What he does is to take a (triangular) comb space, and in the leftmost "tooth" of the comb, he puts another comb, and so on, infinitely in both directions.

[image]

You can, of course, link the chain back on itself into a large circle as well, giving you a compact space.

Now, the theme of the problem in the book is contractibility and deformation reactions, but it works just as well as an example for local path connectedness (or lack thereof).

Comment: Nice example.... Chapter 0? Well, why not? A major-league baseball team once had a player with sweater number $0$, and at the same time , another player with number $00$.

Answer (score 0):

4 lines:

$y=sin(\frac{1}{x}), x >0$

$x = 0$

$x = 10$

$y = 10$

in points (0, $y$) $y \in [-1,1]$ this space is not locally path connected